# How to find a line in a text file

Tags: batch-file

So i was thinking of this, this is supposed to be like a talking simulator, where if you write down something that the batch file does not know, it asks you to write the answer for that question, later creates a text file with the question name, and a line in the text file with the answer. The only problem is that i don't know how to make the batch file read the line inside of the text file. Please help.

```
@echo off
echo Hello!
echo Talk To Me!
pause>nul
:1
cls
echo Enter text
set /p talk=
if exist %talk% (
    goto answer
) else (
    goto dontknow
)
:answer
*finds string in txt file and writes it here*
pause>nul
goto 1
:dontknow
echo I dont know that yet. Teach me what to answer
set /p teach=
echo %teach% >> %talk%.txt
pause>nul
goto 1
```

Comment: [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a .txt file and display it to a batch file. Use the type command. In your case `type %talk%`

Have edited(minor) your code below.

```
   @echo off
echo Hello!
echo Talk To Me!
pause>nul
:1
cls
echo Enter text
set /p talk=
if exist %~dp0%talk%.txt (
    type %talk%.txt
     pause>nul
     goto 1
) else (
    goto dontknow
)

:dontknow
echo I dont know that yet. Teach me what to answer
set /p teach=
echo %teach% >> %talk%.txt
pause>nul
goto 1
```