# Comparing Strings in Batch inside a for (if statement))

Tags: batch-file

I have a file1.txt with some file names. 
I want to read from the file and if the file name contains "xyz" string i need to run some commands and if not some other commands
Not able to do this and need your help,tried a lot of methods but not able to figure out
Here's the sample code i tried:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%i in (file1.txt) do (
     set f=%%i
     set z=XYZ
     echo !f! >>test.txt
     if /i "!f!" == "!z!" (
         echo matched >> test.txt
     ) else ( 
         echo nomatch >> test.txt
     )
 )
```

Comment: To compare whether a string contains another one, you can do it like this: `if "!STRING!"=="!STRING:%SUB%=!" echo Sub-string "%SUB%" found within "!STRING!".` or you use the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html): `find "%SUB%" "file1.txt"` (which returns only those lines within `file1.txt` that contain the sub-string in `%SUB%`; add the `/I` option to do a case-sensitive search)

Comment: Quite interesting that there appear two questions about the [same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43471346) within less than one hour...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: @aschipfl

I tried your code like this :

`@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%i in (file1.txt) do (
set f=%%i
set z=XYZ
echo !f! >>test.txt
if "!f!"=="!f:%z%=!" (
echo matched >> test.txt
) else ( 
echo nomatch >> test.txt
)
)`
But i am getting only "no match" written in test.txt even if XYZ string is present in file1.txt

Comment: @aschipfl's suggestion have an error. The right way is: if the comparison is _different_, then the other substring is contained in the first one; that is: `if "!f!" neq "!f:%z%=!" ( echo matched >> test.txt ) else ( echo nomatch >> test.txt )`. Also, note that in order for this to work you must `set z=XYZ` _before_ the `for` loop...

Comment: You are totally right, @Aacini, thanks for clarification!

Comment: @Aacini


  Thanks a lot . . :) Its working perfectly now. . . Thanks a million times. . .

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks a lot for your help . . . :) was stuck on  this problem for a day. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare whether a string contains another one, you can do it like this (note that this is case-insensitive, because the underlying [sub-string expansion syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) is case-insensitive on its own):

```cmd
if "!STRING!"=="!STRING:%SUB%=!" echo Sub-string "%SUB%" NOT found within "!STRING!"
```

Here the above approach is implemented into your script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INFILE=file1.txt"
set "_OUTFILE=test.txt"
set "_SUBSTR=XYZ"

>> "%_OUTFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=" %%L in ("%_INFILE%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE!
        if not "!LINE!"=="!LINE:%_SUBSTR%=!" (
            echo matched
        ) else ( 
            echo nomatch
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

In addition, I improved the following things:

- constant-like variables are predefined at the beginning;
- the returned text is redirected once only; replace `>>` by `>` to overwrite an already existing file rather than appending to it;
- [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is toggled within the loop in order not to lose exclamation marks in the text; note that the string in `_SUBSTR` must not contain such;
- all file paths used in the script are enclosed within quotation marks;
- the quoted `set` syntax is used throughout the script;
- code indention is used for improved readability;

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html), which returns only those lines within `file1.txt` that contain the sub-string in `%SUB%`; add the `/I` option to do a case-insensitive search:

```cmd
find "%SUB%" "file1.txt"
```

Comment: Thank a ton @aschipfl . . :) I have created the batch file and its working perfectly . .

Comment: Just a quick question . . . This batch file i use only to run in the working directory. . If i create an .exe out of this batch file using iexpress. . . and copy the exe to folder where i want the bat to be executed it doesnt happen because iexpress extracts it to some temp folder. . Is there any work around for this.i.e whichever folder i run the .exe the  .bat file should also get executed in the same folder . . .Please do let me know if i need to post this as a different question. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: You could include the path to the files in the related variables, like: `set "_INFILE=D:\Data\file1.txt"`; or you change that to this: `set "_INFILE=%~1"`, so you can pass the (full) file path as the first command line argument to the batch file...